# Adobe cq5 query builder - get multiple properties within a date range

Tags: adobe, aem, query-builder

I am using queries to search Users based on the property `cq:lastModified` and `jcr:created`
in a specific date range
The query should return the users that has been last modified between the `daterange`, if the last modified property is not present, it should return `jcr:created` in that date range.

Please let me know how it can be done

In debugger, i use this, but please find the path below. I want OR instead of AND

```
path = /home/users
type=rep:User

1_daterange.property=jcr:created
1_daterange.lowerBound=2014-08-18
1_daterange.upperBound=2014-08-19

2_daterange.property=cq:lastModified
2_daterange.lowerBound=2014-08-18
2_daterange.upperBound=2014-08-19



/jcr:root/home/users//element(*, rep:User)
[
(@jcr:created > xs:dateTime('2014-08-18T00:00:00.000+05:30')
and @jcr:created < xs:dateTime('2014-08-19T00:00:00.000+05:30')) 
***AND*** (@cq:lastModified > xs:dateTime('2014-08-18T00:00:00.000+05:30')
and @cq:lastModified < xs:dateTime('2014-08-19T00:00:00.000+05:30')) 
]
```

the 'and' in bold should be actually 'or'

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groups` to search for multiple properties and `group.p.or` to specify `OR` condition

```
path=/home/users
type=rep:User

group.1_daterange.property=jcr:created
group.1_daterange.lowerBound=2014-08-18
group.1_daterange.upperBound=2014-08-19

group.2_daterange.property=cq:lastModified
group.2_daterange.lowerBound=2014-08-18
group.2_daterange.upperBound=2014-08-19

group.p.or=true
```

From the Query Builder API, the `p` in p.or is a special delimiter indicating that what follows (in this case an or) is a parameter of the group, as opposed to a subpredicate of the group, such as 1_daterange.

If no `p.or` is given then all predicates are `ANDed` together.

To know more about querying, refer [this docs page](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html#Sample%20Queries).

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me also. Another **1_relativedaterange.upperBound** will accept -30d, -1M, -1Y. Which are easy to work with sometimes.